# Outputting to console, but on the same line as the last output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to backup our SVN repositories, based on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/powershell/SVNBackupPower.aspx. It works sweet, but when it's waiting for the ZIP to complete, I'd like it to issue a dot instead of a new line each iteration. So,

```
Waiting for ZIP ...................
```

as opposed to

```
Waiting for ZIP
Waiting for ZIP
Waiting for ZIP
Waiting for ZIP
(you get the picture)
```

I guess the equivalent in BASIC from back in the day would be:

```
PRINT ".";
```

But what's the PowerShell equivalent?

Answer (score 8):

Pretty simple...

```
write-host "Waiting for zip" -nonewline
while ($inloop -eq true) {
    write-host "." -nonewline
    $inloop=Get-LoopStatus($Thingy)
}
write-host "."
```

The key is `-nonewline`. You can even make those additional bits different colors via `-foregroundcolor`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I knew it would be, unfortunately, a little more difficult to search for. Have been trawling through all sorts of complicated formatting options.

Comment: as already mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897066/1115187) : `Write-Host writes text to the PowerShell host display, not the pipeline.`, so `Write-Host` is almost always the wrong command

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the write-progress cmdlet to visualize a progress bar.